# Erro ao ao publicar servlet - Java 7 vs Java 8

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, servlet

Aluguei um servidor VPS e ao tentar conectar minha aplicação android com o Java EE, recebi a seguinte mensagem:

> ```
> type Exception report
>
> message app/server/CSelerServer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class app.server.CSelerServer)
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: app/server/CSelerServer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class app.server.CSelerServer)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2899)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
> ```

No servidor, tenho o **WHM/CPanel CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 virtuozzo** e uso a **Apache Tomcat** como servidor de aplicação. No projeto o lado cliente (desktop e móvel) e lado servidor estou usando a JDK 1.8.

Observei que o Tomcat do servidor está usando a JVM 1.7.0

Encontrei dois artigos que dizem o CentOS/Tomcat não suporta Java 1.8

https://blog.cpanel.com/tomcat-support-in-centos-7/

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/tomcat-centos-7.462501/

Entendi errado?

Caso seja isso mesmo, de que forma devo prosseguir?

Voltar para JDK1.7, mudar o servidor de aplicação, mudar de SO no servidor ou mudar o painel de controle?

No localhost está funcionando tudo certo.

Toda ajuda será bem vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parte importante do seu erro é isso:

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

A versão *major/minor* número 52 corresponde ao Java 8. Como você está rodando em um JVM do Java 7, então isso não vai funcionar.

O que está acontecendo é que **você está tentando executar classes compiladas para Java 8 dentro de uma JVM do Java 7**.

No caso, ao menos uma das classes compiladas com Java 8 é a classe `app.server.CSelerServer`.

Assim sendo, há três possíveis soluções:

1. Fazer o upgrade da sua JVM para Java 8.
2. Recompilar as suas classes usando o Java 7. Isso significa não usar quaisquer APIs que foram introduzidas apenas no Java 8, incluindo lambdas, streams, interfaces com métodos *default*, etc.
3. Usar o [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) para dar um jeito de transformar as suas classes do Java 8 em classes do Java 7.

O problema referente a incompatibilidade dos links que você postou diz que o cPanel decidiu não mais dar suporte ao Tomcat. Isso é algo bem diferente do que dizer que não se pode rodar Java 8 dentro de sua máquina virtual. Além disso, nada te impede de rodar o Tomcat fora do cPanel.

O motivo que levou a cPanel a deixar de suportar o Tomcat é que:

- A versão que o cPanel suportava para o Tomcat era antiga demais;
- A quantidade de mudanças em dependências necessárias para atualizar o suporte ao Tomcat seria bem grande e;
- Menos de 0,1% dos clientes do cPanel usavam Tomcat.

Assim sendo, para os desenvolvedores/administradores do cPanel, o melhor para eles foi simplesmente abandonar o Tomcat.

Comment: Compreendi Victor, me preocupa um pouco o fato de ter que voltar para o Java7, tenho uma quantidade muito grande de código, se bem que só precisaria voltar a parte do JavaEE, mas se for essa a solução vou fazê-lo. Não seria o caso de trocar o servidor de aplicação? Conhece algum que suporte o java 8 no cPanel?

Comment: @EdsonFSantos Pelo que andei pesquisando, não dá, mas não tenho certeza absoluta. O que parece é que o cPanel abandonou o Java totalmente e nunca suportou nada além do que o Tomcat. Isso significa que você vai ter que rodar o Tomcat por fora do cPanel. Se preferir Jetty (eu recomendo), Glassfish, WildFly ou algum outro, também vai ter que ser por fora do cPanel. Ou, se realmente quiser manter o cPanel, vai ter que fazer o downgrade e ficar no Tomcat antigo.

Comment: Victor, já estava iniciando o downgrade quando o suporte do VPS colocou o tomcat para funcionar no cPanel com o java8. Me pouparam um trabalhão e agora sabemos que é possível. O app está funcionando com o servidor remoto :)

Comment: @EdsonFSantos Qual versão do Tomcat?

Comment: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 --- JVM 1.8.0_101-b13

Comment: @EdsonFSantos Bem, [de acordo com essa página](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), ele vai funcionar com o Java 6 **ou superior** e com Java 7 **ou superior** se você for usar Websocket. Você vai estar preso a especificação 3.0 do servlet (ou seja, não vai dar para usar detalhes de servlets 3.1 e 4.0, mas esses são bem poucos). Ou seja, só trocar a JVM deve ser realmente o bastante para você.